Drawing and filling a box on a timeline in TikZ
I would like to draw a timeline as pictured in TikZ. I am unsure how to draw boxes on timelines and also on how to fill them in with stripes.
Could anyone help with this?

Thanks!
EDIT 2: After copying the code from the tikz patterns page (btw thanks!!), this is what I get. I am not sure how to move the rectangle down now.
     \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\tikzdeclarepattern{
  name=mylines,
  parameters={
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/size},
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/angle},
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/line width},
  },
  bounding box={
    (0,-0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/line width}) and
    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/size},
0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/line width})},
  tile size={(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/size},
\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/size})},
  tile transformation={rotate=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/angle}},
  defaults={
    size/.initial=5pt,
    angle/.initial=45,
    line width/.initial=.4pt,
  },
  code={
      \draw [line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/line width}]
        (0,0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/size},0);
  },
}

\date{}

\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (3,0);
        \foreach \x in {0.5,1.5,2.5}
        \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);
        \draw [line width=6] (0.5,0) -- (2.5,0);
        node[above=3pt] {$   $};
        node[above=3pt] {$   $};
        \draw[pattern={mylines[size= 2pt,line width= 1pt,angle=70]},
        pattern color=red] (0.5,2.5) rectangle ++(2,0.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



What have you tried?

Look for the hatch pattern about in the middle of https://tikz.dev/library-patterns , which also shows an example.

Please post some code which shows what you tried so far. At least tell us what libraries and packages you looked into and where exactly you got stuck with.

I added the code I tried so far. I only know how to do the basic timeline, not how to put an empty/filled box on top of it.

Thank you. // Just copy from the link I gave you: \usetikzlibrary {patterns,patterns.meta} ...  \begin{tikzpicture}   \draw[pattern={horizontal lines},pattern color=orange]     (0,0) rectangle +(1,1); ...  , which will draw a rectangle over your line(s), when you adjust the coordinates. // Please add to your posted code what's missing to make it compile.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Updated again. Thank you for your patience! The only thing left is to move the rectangle down to the actual timeline

change the coordinates in \draw[pattern={mylines[size= 2pt,line width= 1pt,angle=70]},         pattern color=red] (0.5,2.5) rectangle ++(2,0.5); e.g. change 2.5 and 0.5 to -1 and 1 so the 0 is in the middle, which corresponds to the y coordinate for you timeline. (I think.)

It moves it slightly closer, but also way off the timeline

you don't need to define a whole new pattern, but just use an existing one ;).

@Iris you can ping people who've commented like this. (you would get notified even without my pinging you as I'm commenting on your post, but other people don't get pinged unless there's only one other person involved.)

You don't need to define a new pattern here. You can simply customise Lines. For example,
  \draw [preaction={fill=white},pattern={Lines[angle=70,line width=1pt,distance=2pt,]},pattern color=red] (0.5,3pt) rectangle ++(2,-6pt);

Your nodes are not currently doing anything so I commented them. If you want them to do something, they need to be on a path either between \path and the following ; (or \draw and the ;) or to use \node in place of node. That is,
\node ... {} ;
\path ... node ... {} ;
\draw ... node ... {} ;

are valid provided ... is filled in appropriately, but
node ... {} ;

is not.

\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [->] (0,0) -- (3,0);
  \foreach \x in {0.5,1.5,2.5} \draw (\x cm,5pt) -- (\x cm,-5pt);
  % the next two lines do nothing but create warnings about missing characters on the console
  % perhaps they were meant to be on a path, but they are not valid tikz instructions
  % node[above=3pt] {$   $};
  % node[above=3pt] {$   $};
  \draw [preaction={fill=white},pattern={Lines[angle=70,line width=1pt,distance=2pt,]},pattern color=red] (0.5,3pt) rectangle ++(2,-6pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Personally, I would make line width smaller than 1pt for the pattern or increase the line width of the rectangle's border. fill=white is necessary to avoid seeing the timeline through the pattern. We use preaction for fill - rather than postaction for pattern - so that the border is drawn after the pattern and the fill is behind everything.

Hi! Thank you so much. The only problem left is that the lines this spell out for me are not lines but rather dashes. I just copies in your code, so not sure why it comes out different.

@Iris if you try the code in a new document, do you still get dashes? if so, post the log you get when compiling this example. otherwise, maybe you are setting dashed globally somewhere?
